# How to send picture on mail automatically in android

Tags: android, image, email, camera

I am developing an app in which I want to click Image and automatically after capturing image, the app should send the picture to mail.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imgSaved));
shareIntent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: show us the code which you tried??

Comment: Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imgSaved));
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an intent which will be fired on selection of the image

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("application/image");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Any subject you want to give"); 
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text you want"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/imageYouSelected.jpeg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "sending youer email"));
```

**OR** 
You can use the **JAVA API** approach like [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: Using your code, will attach the picture on Gmail, but I want that the picture should be send automatically to the given Gmail.

Comment: [What  about JAVA api approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

try like this may help you,

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "aa@gmail.com" });
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text of email"); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imgSaved));
shareIntent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I want that that Image should be send on Mail automatically without any user Interaction.